# constant speed of curve,regular curve, and reparametrization by an arc length

Tags: differential-geometry

Question: Show that the curve $\alpha(t)=(sint,t,-cost)$ has a constant speed. Is this curve regular curve? Then find a reparametrization of this curve by an arc lenth.

The curve of $\alpha$ has a constant speed and is a regular curve that can be reparametrized by an arc length. To show that it has a constant speed and is a regular curve we must first find the derivative of $\alpha$.

$\alpha'(t)=(cost,1,sint)$

$|\alpha'(t)|= \sqrt{cos^2(t)+1^2+sin^2(t)}= \sqrt{1+1}= \sqrt{2} $

Since $\alpha'(t) \neq 0$ then it is a regular curve by definition. To find arc length,

$s(t)= \int_{0}^{T} \sqrt{2} dt= \sqrt{2}t |^{T}_{0}= \sqrt{2}T- \sqrt{2}(0)= \sqrt{2}T. $

So, $s= \sqrt{2}T$ or $T= \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Did I finish answering the question? Am I suppose to take a second derivative?

Comment: Yes, your answer is fine, there is no need for second derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed completed the necessary computations, but you could definitely present your solution in a nicer manner!

i.e What is the arc-length parametrization? You have found $T(s)$, so you can define $\text{A} (s) = \alpha(T(s))$.

It would probably help (and be educationally re-enforcing) to write things like "By definition, the speed of the parametrization $\alpha(t)$ is defined to be **__** which is readily seen to be a constant since (insert computation)."

Comment: So it would sound better if I end it by saying: By definition, the reparametrization of $\alpha(t)$ is defined to be  $T= \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}}$ which is a constant since $ |\alpha'(t)|= \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: $T=\frac{s}{\sqrt 2}$ is not a reparametrization per-se. It's an equation expressing the relationship between the arc-length traversed, starting from $t=0$, at time $T$. You really just need one more line saying something like "I can plug $T=\frac{s}{\sqrt 2}$ into the above parametrization to obtain a new parametrization in terms of arc-length."

Comment: Oh ok yea so that's why you use parametrization instead?

Comment: Oh like saying $\alpha'(t)= (cos\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}},1, sin \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}})$

Comment: Not quite. What you've written doesn't quite make sense, as the vector on the right is independent of $t$ **as written**. You would like to re-parametrize $\alpha(t)$ not the velocity.

Comment: Oh gotcha so like this then right $\alpha(t)=(sin\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}},\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}},-cos\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}})$

Comment: ALMOST!!!! Notice that the vector on the right has no t's!!!!! Define a new parametrization $A(s)$ (note this is in terms of arc length which is what we wanteD!!) by $A(s) = \alpha (t(s)) = (sin(\frac{s}{\sqrt 2}, \frac{s}{\sqrt 2}, -cos\frac{s}{\sqrt 2})$

Comment: oh okay I see what you mean. Really it was a matter of how to define the parametrization in terms of arc length. Yeah I can see how that looks nicer. Thank you BlueBuck :)

Comment: You are very welcome :)